# How I can calculate the transaction cost in USD

Tags: ethereum, remix

I have done a transaction on Remix and it costs 199093 gas. At the moment of writing, the gas price is 7.2 Gwei (  $ 0.031 ) [from here ethgas station](https://ethgasstation.info/index.php)

If I want to calculate how much I should pay for this transaction, that means:

199093 * 7.2 = 1433469.6 Gwei = 0.0014334696 eth

and in Dollar, it is 199093 * 0.031 $ = 6171.883 $

is that correct ?? It is too much to pay for only one transaction.

and what about if I want to process the transction faster, that means I will use the gas price 20 Gwei .  [from ethgas station](https://ethgasstation.info/index.php)

so the cost will be much higher..

Any help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last step is incorrect. You multiply `0.0014334696 eth` by the price of ETH, which comes out to roughly $0.31. That is your final cost, not your cost per gwei.

Comment: Based on the site you link, it appears to be the base cost for an ETH transfer, which would be for 21000 gas. What you want is to take your `gasprice*gas consumed` to get your fee in ETH, and then convert it to $ by multiplying it with the ETH price